# What will be the value of i+++i?

Tags: java

I'm new to this community as well in the java. My problem was that I'm curious on what will be the value of **`val`** in this snippet that our professor gave us.

```
int i =3;
int val=i+++i;
```

Please bear with my english.

Comment: why don't you just try it out in a small program?

Comment: If you couldn't ask here, what would you do to find the answer?

Comment: This community will seem extremely harsh to you if you post such questions.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What do you think the output should be? Did you try executing those code segments? Do you have doubt regarding how increment operators work?

Comment: The best way is to try it out on a simple IDE. it wouldnt take much time. i think self learning would go a long way. Well, you can try it first and ask the theory of why does it work this way, but you need to try it out first yourself.

Comment: Hi @omgBob, as stated, Im new to java and don't actually know where to start.

Comment: Hi everyone :) I'm curious on what operation was executed first in that snippet. can somebody help me thanks :)

Comment: Try groovy app console: http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/ just add a new line: ´println val´

Comment: As much as I would love to be welcoming, this is simply not the place for this type of question. Discovering how operations work in Java is something you could easily Google and find many comprehensive tutorials for.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ `i++` is `3` not `4`.

Comment: @RohitJain My bad.. true. i++ is 3 and i is 4 now. Thank for the correction ,as always:)

Comment: @rcc no problem we all started once. Maybe if you asked the question in the way you did in the comment it would have been clearer what you were wondering about. Moreover if you have problems with getting started you probably should try a simple IDE to get you started on java (e.g. BlueJ http://www.bluej.org/)

Comment: @Myth Where did you try that?

Comment: I'm saddened with the responses. Thanks anyways guys.

Comment: @Myth right, `i` ends up 4, and `val` ends up 7.

Answer (score 4):

The unary operator has higher precedence than binary operators, so:

```
i+++i
```

is

```
(i++) + i
```

You might wonder, why it doesn't evaluate to `i + (++i)`. That's because an expression is evaluated from left to right.

Comment: i++ will be executed first?

Answer (score -1):

First the i will be added the value of i and then incremented by one. The result is 7.

Answer (score -1):

val=6

1. **Postfix** operator(i++, i--) have precedence over addictive operators( +, -).
2. Expression will be evaluated from left to right.

So, int val= (i++) + i;

*http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html*